# Is there any MRI sample data in numpy?

Tags: numpy, mri

I would like to try some examples on MRI data on MRI, does Numpy has some MRI sample data?

Comment: `numpy` does not have test data of any sort.

Comment: No, but you can find [several](https://lukas-snoek.com/NI-edu/fMRI-introduction/week_1/python_for_mri.html), [examples](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/SDC-BIDS-IntroMRI/aio/index.html), [online](https://neuraldatascience.io/8-mri/read_viz.html)